# I am trying to add amp-base-carousel but it is not displaying its content

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to add amp-base-carousel but it is not at all displaying its content. When I see in developer tool the divs inside the carousel have display:none property. Please find the screenshots below and code for reference. Please anyone can help here and let me know I am doing anything wrong here and how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Note - I did add the required js file for amp-base-caousel.

Screenshot 1 (in browser not displaying the content)[image]

Screenshot 2 (css display property for divs inside the carousel ) [image]

Below is the code I am using, it is taken basically from the AMP website only, from tutorials section.

```
<amp-base-carousel id="my-carousel">
  <div class="red-gradient">1111</div>
  <div class="blue-gradient">2222</div>
  <div class="green-gradient">33333</div>
</amp-base-carousel>
<div class="buttons" style="margin-top: 8px;">
  <button id='prev-button'>Go to previous slide</button>
  <button id='next-button'>Go to next slide</button>
  <button id='go-to-button'>Go to slide with green gradient</button>
</div>

<script>
    const carousel = document.querySelector('#my-carousel');
    await customElements.whenDefined('amp-base-carousel');
    const api = await carousel.getApi();
    // programatically advance to next slide
    api.next();
    // set up button actions
    document.querySelector('#prev-button').onclick = () => api.prev();
    document.querySelector('#next-button').onclick = () => api.next();
    document.querySelector('#go-to-button').onclick = () => api.goToSlide(2);
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of the component you're using is still in experimental mode. You can either [enable AMP experiments](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/experimental/), or convert to the [stable 0.1 version](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-base-carousel-v0.1/?format=websites).

[Here is a working example](https://playground.amp.dev/#share=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)